# Vacuum Pump Specs

Tags: vacuum, vacuum-pumps

I have an airtight rigid chamber of volume **V** (~500 cu.ft.)

I want to remove the air from the chamber such that the internal pressure is equivalent to some **P** absolute atmospheric pressure (eg 3.46psia)

I would want to evacuate the chamber from ambient pressure **A** (eg 14psia) to **P** within **T** milliseconds (< 1 second)

How would I go about determining the specs for the vacuum pump needed to perform this function? Assume ambient pressure is "on land" and the output of the vacuum is wide open into the environment (minimal resistance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evacuating 10 psi of pressure from a 500 cu ft chamber in under a second is pretty insane. [This](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/vacuum-evacuation-time-d_844.html) is a good calculator, as you will probably need to change your parameters (most likely time) in order to find a suitable pump.

Comment: thank you. that is what i needed.

Comment: Its for a multi-person hypo-bariatric chamber.